# export 宣言されてない分割された JS を node で使う方法はありませんか？

Tags: javascript, node.js

<script> タグで読み込まれているウェブ上の複数ファイルを node で動かしたいです

例えば

```html
<script src="sub.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

となってるときに 2 つのJSファイルをダウンロードして同じディレクトリにおいて
node main
で実行したとき sub.js で定義してあるクラスや関数を使う楽な方法はないでしょうか

複数ファイルを１つにつなぐか

sub.js の中に

```
exports.xxx = xxx;
```

をかいていくしかないんでしょうか？

できれば main の方は書き換えてもいいんですが
sub の方になるべく手を入れずに実現したいですが方法はないでしょうか

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> できれば main の方は書き換えてもいいんですが
> sub の方になるべく手を入れずに実現したいですが方法はないでしょうか

[script.runInThisContext()](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_script_runinthiscontext_options) を使う方法も考えられます。

**main.js**

```
function include_extra_file(path) {
  const fs = require('fs');
  const vm = require('vm');
  vm.runInThisContext(fs.readFileSync(path));
}

include_extra_file('./sub.js');

// main
console.log('main');
sub();
```

**sub.js**

```
function sub() {
  console.log('sub');
}
```

**実行結果**

```sh
$ node main
main
sub
```

Answer (score 1):

複数ファイルを１ファイルにまとめる方法がうまくいくのであれば、次の方法でもうまくいくと思います。

```
cat main.js sub.js | node
```